# How do I update a tuple in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

There are literary no tutorials on how to update tuples on Google.
Can someone explain how tuples can be updated in Cassandra?

Answer (score 2):

The CQL `tuple` data type is implicitly "frozen" without needing the CQL `frozen` keyword so you can't update individual elements of a `tuple` column -- you need to update the whole column.

To illustrate, here's my example CQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE sensors (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    location tuple<decimal, decimal>,
    temperature decimal,
    weight int
)
```

Here's an example where I insert a sensor with its location:

```
INSERT INTO sensors (id, location)
    VALUES ('abc123', (50.4501, 30.5234));
```

Here's an example where I update the location of a sensor:

```
UPDATE sensors
    SET location = (47.0971, 37.5434)
    WHERE id = 'abc123';
```

For details, see [CQL tuple type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/tupleType.html). Cheers!